USB 2.0 bus issues with signal integrity
I have a USB 2.0 Bus that has errors with certain cable/hub combinations. Looking at the signals, they look awful (1GHz differential probe 50Ω).


As far as routing goes,  the total length is about 4" long to the connector and has an ESD diode along the way.
The signals are run underneath a capacitor, which is probably not good:

And we have added some pogo pin pads for flashing in production environment.

I don't think the pogo pads are creating issues as they only add 10fF to the bus and the vias add 1.4nH of inductance to the stub. My problem is not with signaling through the pogos, but through the connector.
Has anyone had any issues with USB 2.0 and an ESD diode like the ESDS312?
Can anyone see any issues with this design or explain the poor differential signaling?
Here is a pic of the probe (usb cable removed for visibility)

The solder doesn't look that great, it's not wetting around the pins of the USB connector:


To be sure, thats 480 Mbps? What impedance matching you used and the traces go over a ground plane, right? Is that a 2 or 4 layer board? The differential probe is high-z and does not terminate, right?

Yes 480. Yes over ground plane, I have 90Ω lines (AFAIK) the PCB MFG might have messed with the Dk. It's a 12 layer board. I am not sure about the diff probe, it's a TDP3500 from tektronix. I couldn't get good signaling with two 1GHz SE probes either.

Have you tried removing the ESD protection? Different cables? Which USB chip that U10 is? Only the length matching on the Type-C pads seems it could be handled better but it should not be that bad. Is the connector rated for 480 Mbps (quite sure it is but for charging it does not need to be)?

@Justme I guess I could have gone with a via, but then you add inductance on one line with ~3nH, over routing on the single layer, which method do you prefer?

I could, I don't think it is the ESD protection, this has worked on previous designs. I can't really say what the U10 is for IP reasons, it's a video chip and the datasheets are NDA'ed. The connector is rated for USB 2.0 speeds

Well, due to the Type-C pad layout, it's always a compromise. Compared to 3nH and say 1.6mm track length per via (and uneven amount of vias being bad anyway), how much nH or skew is that piece of non-differential track? It may be insignificant at even 480 Mbps speeds. It seems no problem is seen in the design. Broken connector, oxidized, or full of flux, bad contact? REXT correct value?

How do you make the measurements? What is your test fixture?

@Ale..chenski With an MSO68 with a TDP3500 diff probe limited to 1GHz (50Ω). I'm probing directly to pins on the ESDS312 with the diff probe.

What does the normal or common mode waveform look like? What does the probing setup look like (photograph)?

@TimWilliams Picture provided. What do you mean by commond mode waveform? (I think you can kind of see this in the top pic, I'd have to hook up the SE probes to get what it looks like WRT ground

@Justme Posted a pic of the contacts, it's not the best soldering job but it should get the job done. No Rext or mention of it in the documentation, the device also supports USB 3.1 so maybe that is the reason why no Rext?

@VoltageSpike You have 200 ohm Rext at the chip. And also the probe is purely differential - no ground reference at all? If for some reason the ground of the USB device floats (e.g. connected to laptop, no other connections anywhere) compared to scope (likely ground tied to mains PE via mains cord) it may have too much common mode between grounds to see the differential well. Anyway USB2 is not purely differential - it's ground referenced and partly single-ended.

1. "No Rext or mention of it in the documentation" Isn't R73 (Rext = 200 Ω) populated? 2. "... that has errors with certain cable/hub combinations" Can you rule out that the cables, connectors and hubs aren't the cause of this issue? In the past we've had issues with all three of them. 3. You wrote "I have 90Ω lines (AFAIK) the PCB MFG might have messed with the Dk" Is there a way for you to verify the differential (90Ω ±10%) and single-ended (45Ω ±10%) impedances?

@Velvet 1) I thought these would show up as pulldowns. I did not see Rext in my own sch because I was looking for resistors attached to the lines. 2) My main problem is software devs that don't want to have to change their habits, the intitial reports of things not working were with extension cables which are not part of the USB spec. 3) I did just verify the stackup and my impedance is 82Ω, the MFG was supposed to retouch USB 2.0 lines with their stackup and did not, but it's still within ±10%

The slower bounce could track with various things: cable reflections (waves within cable; mismatch), shield currents (plus CM-DM mode conversion), interference from elsewhere on the board (again most likely needing a mode conversion mechanism); crosstalk in the cable, bad cable shielding or connector fitness, etc.

@VoltageSpike Afaik, having around 85 ohms or even 82 is actually sometimes beneficial and even recommended - but forgot if it was only for USB3 or for USB2 too.

@Justme Well, that is good to know. Do you think I could lower Rext and get a better common mode voltage to make it show up on the scope?

"My main problem is software devs that don't want to have to change their habits, the intitial reports of things not working were with extension cables which are not part of the USB spec." The SW devs shouldn't be the ones making this decision. If cabling, hubs and extenders aren't USB certified, I wouldn't lift a finger. (I've wasted so many hours in the past with problems caused by substandard equipment. Especially USB).

@Velvet We did tell them they can't use extenders and that they aren't part of the USB spec. Some of the cables still don't work, I'm trying to get the word out on the cables. But I really don't have a choice when my boss thinks it looks bad.

@VoltageSpike No I meant just check the Rext value - if chip requires 200 ohms 1% then make sure there is one - or if it should be some other value and 1%.

@VoltageSpike USB_REXT could be for setting analog parameters for the USB Phy. On searching for that term, on a selection of random datasheets containing a USB_REXT found descriptions such as Connect to GND with a 3 kOhm 1% resistor. I.e. an incorrect value for USB_REXT might cause issues such as a lower than expected transmit voltage - noted as part of the answer. If the data for U10 is under a NDA perhaps you need to ask the device manufacturer to confirm what the USB_REXT value should be.

Probing USB2 HS (480Mbps) signals in the middle of transmission line is not the right way to evaluate signal quality. You should use a properly constructed fixture that plugs into your connector. Like this one:

(this one seems to be the least expensive on today's market).
Or you can easily make your own, from a Type-C breakout mini-board and two good coax cables with SMA ends.
For the host you must have a software tool to generate the standard "compliance packet", and get a eye diagram out of it. And you should try to get the same eye diagram at the end of USB-certified 5-m long cable, using a similar test fixture. The eye diagrams must meet near-end and far-end specifications including jitter and edge monotonicity. And yes, all this costs money.
But simply looking at your trace, I think the major problem is that you have the signal of just +-250 mV, while at the transmitting port you should have +-400mV nominal. So, this signal won't work on long cables with sloppy extenders.
CORRECTION: It looks like the question is about a USB device, not host. Then the +-250mV at the receiving end is normal, due to usual cable attenuation. The presented signal is an average of streams of SOFs. And every SOF has unique and incrementing frame number. So the data shape after the always the same sync pattern varies, and with infinite persistence the trace always will look "smudged". So the presented trace is no indication of bad signal integrity, and in fact it looks like it should be when infinite persistence is turned on. Except that there is a deficiency in the signal right after the steady sync pattern, the amplitude of the circled area is marginal:

(or it could be again the effect of persistent mode of the scope)
As I said in the body of answer, the device must be put into a steady compliance mode and the eye diagram must be derived and evaluated for compliance to USB test specifications.
For device side it is more complicated to get the compliance pattern out. You must have another special test fixture with RF relays. After the device gets enumerated and host software directs the device to compliance mode, the RF relay redirects the USB bus to test SMA connectors (or simple pin headers, if high-impedance diff probe is used), and the eye diagram should be evaluated, just as for USB hosts.
